# How to load iPhone UIViewController from Unity3d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, unity-game-engine

I am developing one game application and i want to give login functionality to user. So i am planning to show Login view which is developed in xCode but how can i show it when my unity3d game is running. Means if user click on Login button from Unity3d it should show LoginView from xCode native.

can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a plugin to interface between the Obj-C and Unity's C#. Here is the page that discusses plugins: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

At the bottom, there are some links to help you with setting up the code.

I believe that this is included in Unity iOS. Otherwise, it requires Unity Pro.

Comment: First you need to create plugin which will call from Unity3D to iPhone and from that Method call you have add your view to UIWindow.

Comment: If anybody facing this issue then i can help them.

Comment: Hi Yashsh, I want to add UnityView in my iOS app. can you help me regarding it?